# Prove, that x, y, z fulfill this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got the following problem I can't solve myself.

Prove, that **if** x, y, z fulfill this equation:
$$
x+y=z+2015
$$
$$
x^2+y^2=z^2+2015^2
$$
**then:**
$$
x^3+y^3=z^3+2015^3
$$

Comment: What are $x$, $y$ and $z$?  You can't show they fulfill equations if you don't know something more about them than just their names.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you're asking. Do you want a solution (if one exists) for that system? Have you omitted some additional hypothesis?

Comment: Your question is not clear the solutions of your system are all $x,y,z$ such that $ \{x,y\}=\{z,2015\}$

Comment: If you are looking for solutions to $x,y,z$ ... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%3Dz%2B2015%2C+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3Dz%5E2%2B2015%5E2%2C+x%5E3%2By%5E3%3Dz%5E3%2B2015%5E3+

Comment: I bet the OP means something like: prove that any two of the given equations imply the third one.

Comment: I've just edited the question, I'm sorry for the mistake. Now it seems to be clear :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pure algebra solution.

Note:

$$ (x+y)^2 = (z + 2015)^2 = z^2 + 2 \cdot 2015z + 2015^2 $$

and:

$$ (x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = z^2 + 2015^2 + 2xy $$

equating these two, we have $xy = 2015z$. Now:

$$ x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)(x^2 - xy + y^2) = (z + 2015)(z^2 + 2015^2 - 2015z) = z^3 + 2015^3 $$

Answer (score 2):

The system given by the first two equations has trivially two solutions, given by $(x,y)=(z,2015)$ and $(x,y)=(2015,z)$. Since such a system cannot have more than two solutions, we have just listed all of them, and it follows that $x^3+y^3=z^3+2015^3$ in any case.